# Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference on line 12

Tags: perl

So I am trying to teach myself perl as a new language.  I find the best way to learn a new language is to set myself a project.  This project is a text game.  I have just started this evening.  I need to take input from the user and then write it to a file.  As I am going to be doing this over and over again, I thought it would be best to put the code in subroutines, as you can see below.

The only problem is that I keep getting the following error:
    Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference at book1.pl line 12, <> line 2.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = 'save.txt';
sub open_save{
    open(my $fh, '>', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
}
sub close_save{
    close my $fh;
}
print "Welcome to the 40K universe\nWhat is your first name?";
my $first_name = <>;
print"What is your surname?";
my $surname = <>;
my $name = $first_name . $surname;
open_save();
print "$name";
close_save();
```

Comment: `my` declares _local_ variables.

Comment: In `open_save` you open a filehandle, but scope it to within that subroutine. So it's instantly closed and the variable is invalid.

Comment: @Sobrique Thanks a lot man that makes it a lot clearer :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`my` creates and returns a new variable. You pass this new variable to `close`, which quite legitimately complains that it's not a file handle.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub open_save {
    my ($filename) = @_;
    open(my $fh, '>', $filename)
       or die "Can't open file '$filename': $!\n";
    return $fh;
}

sub close_save {
    my ($fh) = @_;
    close $fh;
}

{
    my $filename = 'save.txt';
    ...
    my $fh = open_save($filename);
    print $fh "$name\n";
    close_save($fh);
}
```